# Github repo's contributors page is not updating the number of commits, additions, and deletions

Tags: github

On the contributors page, under my Github username, it would say for example
100 commits 10,000 ++ 5000 --

My recent commits are in fact showing up in the list of commits under my username when I click on the link referenced by "100 commits". I'm just not sure why the contributors page is not updating it to something like 101 commits 10,100 ++ 5100 --

Comment: You may find better help at https://github.community/

Comment: It takes time to update, how much time has it been since you made those commits?